# Linux shell script, checking input from user

Tags: linux, shell

So I'm making a simple bash shell script calculator and I ran into a snag.

I can't seem to find out to see if the user has inputted + or - or / or *

I'm not sure what I should try to write. I know that

```
echo "Enter + or - "
read input2
if [ $input2 = "+" ] then
    echo "You entered $input2"
```

doesn't work. So what should I put to read for the basic operators?

Edit: Bash shell is being used

Comment: Make sure you quote your variables. Otherwise, `*` will be expanded as a filename wildcard.

Comment: What shell do you use?

Comment: Please post the actual script example. It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong. I'm not even sure if you used the backticks in your question for SO markup or because that's what you actually have in the script.

Comment: Try -eq instead of =

Comment: Try adding a semicolon before `then`.

Comment: You also need to end with fi, and as user4098326 said, you either need    ]; then or to put then on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, semicolon or newline is needed before `then`.

Double quotes variables to prevent expansion which might lead to syntax errors:

```
if [ "$input" = '+' ] ; then
```

You can also switch to `[[ ... ]]` conditionals which don't require quoting of the arguments:

```
if [[ $input = + ]] ; then
    echo You entered +
fi
```

You have to quote `*` on the right hand side, though, otherwise it's interpreted as a wildcard pattern, meaning "anything".

Answer (score 0):

Try  the if statement like:

```
if [ $input = "+" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having some serious syntax problems. Here's a refined one:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter + or - "
read input2
if [ "$input2" = "+" ]; then
    echo "You entered $input2"
fi
```

Output:

```
Enter + or - 
+
You entered +
```

You can print something with read too, during input.

```
read -p "Enter + or - " input2
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach would be to use bash case statements instead of if conditions for this calculator script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter + or - or * or /"
read input2
case $input2 in
'+' )
echo "You entered $input2" ;;
'-' )
echo "You entered $input2" ;;
'*' )
echo "You entered $input2" ;;
'/' )
echo "You entered $input2" ;;
* )
echo "Invalid input"
;;
esac
```

Please note the difference between the case '*' and the last case * (without the single quotes). The first one will match the '*' symbol literally but the last one (without single quotes) represents wild card. The last option is a wild card used to catch all invalid inputs which don't match any of the cases we are looking for.

The above script can also be modified to be much shorter.

```
echo "Enter + or - or * or /"
read input2
case $input2 in
'+'|'-' |'*' |'/' )
echo "You entered $input2" ;;
* )
echo "Invalid input"
;;
esac
```

Here it will look for '+' or '-' or '*' or '/' in a single case and print $input2 else it will default to print "invalid input".

You can read more about case statements here http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html